# Upgrading Mythbuntu 10.10 to 12.04

Tags: 10.10, upgrade, 12.04, mythbuntu

Hoping for some pointers to the right upgrade path for upgrading my working 10.10 Mythbuntu system to 12.04 of the same.

The notes for 12.04 say to ensure you've upgraded to mythtv .25, via the specially provided PPA's but not sure at what point is best to do that?

Any one doing this?  Any pointers/gotcha's?

Any help appreciated; googling and FAQ's have not been much help with a version this 'old'.. :-)

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

1) Upgrading directly from 10.10 to 12.04 isn't supported. You would need to upgrade to 11.04, then 11.10, then 12.04. At this point, probably better/easier to backup everything, install 12.04, then restore everything. (I usually recommend a fresh install anyway)

2) Upgrading to 12.04 will upgrade MythTV to 0.25 at the same time (0.25 ships with 12.04). That said, I've seen numerous recommendations that you shouldn't upgrade both at the same time and that you should upgrade MythTV first, then upgrade the distro. (I usually run the latest version of MythTV anyway, so I've personally never tested upgrading both at the same time)

3) To upgrade the MythTV version, you will need to enable the [Mythbuntu repos](http://www.mythbuntu.org/repos), select 0.25 in the Mythbuntu Control Centre, then update the machine as usual. (I recommend having this repo enabled as it gives you new builds from the MythTV fixes branch)

Comment: Thanks for this; the mythbuntu repo allowed me to upgrade to .24 effortlessly (thanks MythBuntu Team!).  Now I 'just' need to do an OS upgrade, but it was the MythTV version I really needed.